# $.fn.yiiListView is undefined error

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I have the following CListView

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$ligas,
        'viewData'=>array('joinedArray'=>$joinedArray),
        'pager' => array( 
                                         'prevPageLabel'=>'< Prev',
                                         'nextPageLabel'=>'Next >',
                                         'header'=>'Page: ',
                                         'pageSize'=>5,),
        'itemView'=>'_viewSearch',
        'emptyText'=>'empty',
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:paintMyLigas()',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", //template
        'pagerCssClass'=>'page-number',//contain class
        'id'=>'idCListView',
    ));
```

And then a javascript function which is supposed to trigger an ajax update on this list

```
function updateList(){
    $.fn.yiiListView.update('idCListView'); 
}
```

I get the following error:
$.fn.yiiListView is undefined

Any ideas? pls i need help!! :)
Thanks in advance

**Edit** @ldg , there are several js files being included and since (evidently) I am no expert with html and web programming in general, i added all those which seemed relevant.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../../Javascript/main/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../../images/advertisementSpaces/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/93fda158/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Javascript/main/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Javascript/main/floating.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/93fda158/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Do you notice any conflicts here that could lead to this error?

Comment: What Yii JS are you including on the page?

Comment: @Michael Mior
This is the only script i'm including:
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
Should i include something else?

Comment: That's your problem then. You need to include Yii's libraries into your page.

Comment: @Michael Mior
I thought they were already included.. How should i do this then?

Comment: Check the source of your page to see what's already included.

Comment: I checked.. but since i don't know exactly what it is that i need to include, i don't know what to look for. I use all JQuery functions without any kind of problem, which js file is it that for this one in particular i need to include manually? Thanks a lot @Michael!

Comment: Does the page you are in dynamically load HTML from a Yii view, and does that view use one or more zii widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Default functionality would be to render the page with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/5764d9e2/jquery.js"></script>
```

in the header, and:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/a488eed5/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js"></script>
```

in the footer. There might be some others as well, like "jquery.ba-bbq.js", etc. The version of jQuery will depend on the Yii version you are using (current is 1.6), so it could be causing problems if you are loading two versions of jQuery. As mentioned, check the *rendered* source to see what js has been included.

You should also see a generated jQuery function in the footer including something like a "yiiListView" function to init the pager and sorter, etc. -- if not, that could also indicate a problem.

Comment: I added the scripts which are being included, maybe you can notice any mistaake? thank you very much!

Comment: try not including any of the jquery on your own, I see 3 versions there - in fact, you might be best off creating a page (view) that doesn't use any of your own js at all to avoid any conflicts and get your list view working first. Yii should include the jquery it needs when you declare the zii widget.